# Visual Studio 2015 - Prevent debugger stepping into STL code (specfically std::function) but still step into any usercode the stl calls to

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to make debugging std::function-heavy code less of a nightmare.  What I want to happen is to be able to do is step directly into the lambda body in this example:

```
std::function<void(void)> lam_dostuff = []() {
    printf("stuff has been done\n");
};

lam_dostuff();
```

I did some research and found out that the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter` file contains step-into overrides.  I can add the rule `<Function><Name>std::.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>`, and this does prevent me from stepping into any stl code, but it also prevents stepping into user code that is called as a result of the stl call.  I tried adding the rule `<Function><Name>std::_Invoker_functor::_Call.*</Name><Action>StepInto</Action></Function>`, the signature for the final step of a std::function invocation, to no avail.

Is there anything I can do to get the result I want?

Comment: I found the same question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7f46806-d407-4c3e-ab86-04303ae5e5e7/how-to-step-directly-into-my-stdfunction-in-debugger. It looks like this is not possible at the moment unfortunately.