# How to disallow my debugger (totalview) to step into the standard library implementation?

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, totalview

Is it possible to disallow my debugger ([totalview](https://www.roguewave.com/products-services/totalview)) to step into the standard library code on linux? Quite often when debugging C++ code I step into standard library code. I expect that it is correct; I am not interested in debugging it. I am only interested in debugging my own (self-written) code.

For instance when setting a break point at this function:

```
foo(std::make_shared<int>(6));
```

where `foo` is defined as:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<int> x) {
    // do something
}
```

I do not want to dive into the details of `std::make_shared`: what I want is to step directly into the function foo. But this seems not to be possible. If the breakpoint at `foo(std::make_shared<int>(6));` is reached and I press the 'Step Into' button it first steps into the 'memory' header file (standard library):

You can double click on the function, than place a breakpoint and go to it and remove the breakpoint. This works, but is time consuming and cumbersome.

The very same problem is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352426/skip-stl-code-when-debugging-c-code-in-visual-studio-2012) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450489/visual-studio-2015-prevent-debugger-stepping-into-stl-code-specfically-stdf), for visual studio but not for totalview.

Comment: Do you have an option to Step Over?  In MSVS that will go to the next line.

Comment: Yes, you can step over a function.

Comment: Okay.  It isn't the best think but what I do is set the breakpoint in the function that I want to check and then I'll hit that breakpoint even if use step over.  You could also try using step out to get out of the library code and back to yours.

Comment: In parallel to your comment, I edited my question in the very same way. :-)